# Special values of partial Zeta functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $\mathfrak m$ be an integral ideal of a number field $F$, let $C$ be a class in the ray class group $J^{\mathfrak m}/P^{\mathfrak m}$ modulo $\mathfrak m$ and define

$\zeta(C,s)=\sum_{\mathfrak a\in C, \mathfrak a \ integral}\frac{1}{N(\mathfrak a)^s}$

For totally real $F$, Shintani proved a formula for the value $\zeta(C,1-k)$ when $k\geq 1$ is an integer.

When $\mathfrak m$ is nontrivial, are there some results (or even tables) in the literature giving the rational number $\zeta(C,-1)$ for small $C$, $\mathfrak m$ and $F$? (e.g. for $C=[\mathcal O_F]$, $\mathfrak m=2\mathcal O_F$ and $F=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{p})$ with $p\leq 11$ prime)